# How do I add a progress bar while loading xml and images from internet and then show listview

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, download, oncreate

I'm developing a app with an activity that via an intent starts this activity. This activity consists of  a list view populated with text from a xml and images, the xml and images needs to be downloaded during oncreate.

My question: How do I transform this code into running the download parts in a separate thread and displaying a progressbar during download and then hiding the progressbar when  the list is ready?

Only attaching the OnCreate:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_video_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String FIRCONEURL = b.getString("url");
    mIsPremium = b.getString("isPremium");


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(FIRCONEURL); // getting XML from URL
    xmltest = xml;
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    testdocument = doc;
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);


    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
        map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
        map.put("nummerilista", parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        allyoutubeids.add(parser.getValue(e, "youtubeid"));
        songsList.add(map);

    }

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList, mIsPremium);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            String youtubeid = String.valueOf(id);
            String delims = "<id>"+String.valueOf(id+1)+"</id>";
            String[] tokens = xmltest.split(delims);
            String[] tokens1 = tokens[1].split("<youtubeid>");
            String[] tokens2 = tokens1[1].split("</youtubeid>");
            youtubeid = tokens2[0];

            //Start video if Premium, else only start the first in the list
            if (mIsPremium.contains("YES")){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(pick_video_main.this, PlayVideo.class);
                if (repeat) {
                    int number = 1;
                    while (number <= 50) {
                        repeatyoutubeids.add(youtubeid);
                        number++;
                        Log.d("pick_video_main:", "Adding YoutubeID");
                    }
                    Log.d("pick_video_main: repeatyoutubeids", repeatyoutubeids.toString());
                    myIntent = new Intent(pick_video_main.this, PlayAll.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("key", repeatyoutubeids);
                    pick_video_main.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
                else {
                    myIntent.putExtra("key", youtubeid);
                    pick_video_main.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
                }


            else{

                //Handle non-premium
                if(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(id))>3){
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(pick_video_main.this);
                    builder.setMessage("To enjoy the full content and features and to support the development of this app please purchase/donate premium")
                            .setTitle("Donate and go premium");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Donate and get premium now!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            start_purchase();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Not now thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                }

                else {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(pick_video_main.this, PlayVideo.class);
                    if (repeat) {
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                    myIntent.putExtra("key", youtubeid);
                    pick_video_main.this.startActivity(myIntent);}

                }

        }
    });

    Log.d("pick video main", "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d("pick video main", "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                Log.d("Problem setting up in-app billing: ", "BLÄ");
                return;
            }

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d("pick video main", "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: use `AsyncTask` and their `callback` methods. try this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: `AsyncTask`is your solution , check this tutorial : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/182/show-progressbar-while-downloading-image-using-asynctask-in-android/